# PHP Newsletter form not submitting

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some issues with a php newsletter form. The form won't submit/send the input data to my email.

It's giving me a confirmation message on the site when I fill out the form, but it's not forwarding the data.

Do you guys have any clue what might be wrong?

This is the html form:

```
                <div class="span3" id="footerNavNewsletter">
            <h6 class="Newslettersignup"><?php abc('newsletter_register');?></h6>
            <div id="reg-response"></div>
                    <!-- <form class="newsletter" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" method="post"> -->
            <form class="newsletter" name="newsletter" id="newsletterForm" method="post" data-async data-target="reg-response" action="<?php echo get_permalink(1372); ?>">
              <?php wp_nonce_field('nimbus_newsletter_nonce', '__nimbus_action_nonce'); ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
              <?php wp_referer_field( true ) ?>

              <input type="email" name="newsletter_email" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_email');?>" class="newsletterInput">
              <input type="text" name="newsletter_fullname" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_fullname');?>" class="newsletterInput">
              <input type="text" name="newsletter_company" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_company'); ?>" class="newsletterInput">
              <input type="text" name="newsletter_country" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_country'); ?>" class="newsletterInput">
              <input type="submit" id="submitNewsletter" value="<?php abc('newsletter_signup') ;?>" class="newsletterInput btn">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

    <hr>
    <p>Copyright © 2017 Nimbus Nordic A/S. All rights reserved</p>
</div>

</footer>
<div class="modal hide" id="newsletterModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h4 class="add_top_margin">Sign Up for Nimbus News</h4>
    <div id="modal-response"></div>
  </div>
  <form class="newsletter newsletterForm" name="newsletter" id="newsletterForm" method="post" data-async data-target="modal-response" action="<?php echo get_permalink(1372); ?>">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('nimbus_newsletter_nonce', '__nimbus_action_nonce'); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
        <?php wp_referer_field(true); ?>

        <input type="email" name="newsletter_email" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_email');?>" class="newsletterInput">
        <input type="text" name="newsletter_fullname" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_fullname');?>" class="newsletterInput">
        <input type="text" name="newsletter_company" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_company'); ?>" class="newsletterInput">
        <input type="text" name="newsletter_country" placeholder="<?php abc('newsletter_form_country'); ?>" class="newsletterInput">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"><?php abc('close'); ?></button>
      <input type="submit" id="submitNewsletter" value="<?php abc('newsletter_signup');?>" class="newsletterInput btn" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my .php document:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['__nimbus_action_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['__nimbus_action_nonce'], 'nimbus_newsletter_nonce')) {


    $name = get_bloginfo('name');
    $to = 'st@nimbusnordic.com';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    // $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <'.$to.'>'."\r\n";

    $n_mail = $_POST['newsletter_email'];
    $n_fullname = $_POST['newsletter_fullname'];
    $n_country = $_POST['newsletter_country'];
    $n_company = $_POST['newsletter_company'];


    $subject = 'New Newsletter Subscriber';
    $content = '
                A new Newsletter subscriber has been added.<br />
                Information about the subscriber:<br /><br />
                <strong>Email address</strong>: ' .$n_mail. '<br />
                <strong>Full name</strong>: ' . $n_fullname . '<br />
                <strong>Country:</strong> ' .$n_country.'<br />
                <strong>Company:</strong> ' . $n_company;

     $referrer = wp_get_referer();
    if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
      echo 'Thank you for signing up to our newsletter!';
        // wp_redirect( add_query_arg('newsletter', 'success', $referrer) );
    //   exit;
    } else {
      echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again!';
      // wp_redirect( add_query_arg('newsletter', 'failed', $referrer) );
      // exit;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Which message is outputting? Have you tried var_dumping the data?

Comment: Is your PHP server capable of sending emails? Which message do you get output? Did you try this form on another server already?
Lack of information...

Comment: @Dominik Hey, sorry for the lack of information - this is out of my expertise.. I'm not quite sure if it's, how do I check? The message I get output is the following: "Thank you for signing up to our newsletter!". I have not tried the form on another server.

Comment: @MarkOverton Hey Mark, the message I get output is:
"Thank you for signing up to our newsletter!"

How do I var_dump?

Comment: @SebastianTramp Please try inserting `mail("st@nimbusnordic.com","Test","Test");` above the `echo 'Thank you for signing up to our newsletter!';` and see if the mail is being received.

Comment: do `var_dump($to, $subject, $content);` and make sure all the correct info is there.

Comment: @Dominik Nothing is being forwarded, unfortunately. I've tried 2 different emails. Might this be a .php problem? We're running an old version of wordpress (3.7.3.), could this also cause issues?

Comment: Well, the function I provided is correct - so we narrowed the issue down to being something caused by your server or hoster.
Have a look at your hosters website if they support PHP mailing. Some don't as a SPAM prevention measure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. Your server may be not allowed/able to send emails. check with your sever operator/partner.

Though, check with simple mail function like below.

```
wp_mail("Your_email_address", "test", "check email sending");
```

Comment: Hi Vishal,

I tried adding the wp_mail function to my functions.php, and now the site is down with a HTTP ERROR 500.

Is this a clear sign of a .php issue?

Comment: It was as following:

function wp_mail ("sebtramp@gmail.com", "test", "check email sending");

Comment: why you used "function" keyword before wp_mail function?

Comment: Spur of the moment.

Do I simply just add this directly to the functions.php, and then it will send a test email?

wp_mail ("sebtramp@gmail.com", "test", "check email sending");

Comment: yes,it will send mail.

if you not got mail then it's server/hosting side issue you have to discuss with server administrator

Answer (score -2):

You can add a new attribute to submit button for "name" as "submitted". Because you're checking `"$_POST['submitted']"` variable but it is not defined according to I see.

Comment: It is defined as a hidden field: `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />`